# How to plot for frequency only?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

### Question

How can I plot the following scenario, just like shown in the attached image? This is for the purpose of visualising frequency allocation in a network

### Scenario

I have a range of frequency values in a list-tuple like so, where the 1st value is the centre frequency, 2nd is total width, 3rd is guard band:

```
frequencies = [('195.71250000', '59.00000000', '2.50000000'), ('195.78750000', '59.00000000', '2.50000000'), ('195.86250000', '59.00000000', '2.50000000')]
```

and the range of these values are:

```
range = [('191.32500000', '196.12500000')]
```

Note: These are dummy values, the actual data is much larger but follows the same general structure
[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: You can separate those values from array by using `lambda` function like `cent_fc = list(map(lambda i : i[0], frequencies))` and these will give you only `center frequency` values and same way you can get `width` with `width = list(map(lambda i : i[1], frequencies))`. and use those to plot `rectangle` wave with `center` and `width`.

Comment: @JayPatel sorry I'm aware of how to get the centre values and the widths from the list, what I need help with is how to plot a rectangle with the plot including the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to create this plot. One way is to use [`ax.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-vlines) to plot the dashed lines for the frequencies and to use [`ax.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-bar) for the rectangles representing the frequency ranges.

Here is an example where the frequencies are occupied at regular intervals within the range you have given (boundaries included) but with widths of randomly varying size. No guards are computed seeing as they should be automatically apparent thanks to the position of the frequencies and the widths, as far as I understand.

Also, the widths are much smaller compared to the sample data you have provided, else the bars will be very wide and will all overlap with one another, which would look very different from the image you have shared.

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)  # random number generator
frequencies = np.arange(191.325, 196.125, step=0.3)
widths = rng.uniform(0.05, 0.25, size=frequencies.size)

# Create figure with single Axes and loop through frequencies and widths to plot
# vertical dashed lines for the frequencies and bars for the widths
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
for freq, width in zip(frequencies, widths):
    ax.vlines(x=freq, ymin=0, ymax=10, colors='tab:blue', linestyle='--', zorder=1)
    ax.bar(x=freq, height=6, width=width, color='tab:blue', zorder=2)

# Additional formatting
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (THZ)', labelpad=15, size=12)
ax.set_xticks(frequencies[::2])
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
for spine in ['top', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: frequencies]

Comment: Accepted as answer, this was the exact solution I want to implement!